# getting Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an expression with upgrades

Tags: weblogic, jstl

Hi I am upgrading my Enterprise Struts web application with new Struts, Weblogic and Oracle DB.
Struts from 2.3.32 to 2.5.13
Weblogic 12.1.3 to 12.2.1.3
Oracle 11g to Oracle to 12C

I downloaded related jars for Struts and changed the web.xml file for Servlet 3.1 version. Downloaded the JSTL 1.2 jar and removed the old jstl jars from the classpath.

I removed the standard.jar as part of removing the Old JSTL jar.

But I am getting the below errors when I start the weblogic locally.

```
<Oct 19, 2017 9:20:26,113 AM EDT> <Notice> <JMX> <BEA-149512> <JMX Connector Server started at service:jmx:iiop://172.26.186.55:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.>
<Oct 19, 2017 9:20:26,707 AM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STANDBY.>
<Oct 19, 2017 9:20:26,707 AM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING.>
<Oct 19, 2017 9:20:26,738 AM EDT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170036> <The Logging monitoring service timer has started to check for logged message counts every 30 seconds.> 
<Oct 19, 2017 9:20:57,804 AM EDT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101212> <cpsent:cpsent Failure while precompiling JSPs: weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: refferenceEdit.jsp:35:29: Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an expression.
                     <c:out value="${metaData.tableName}"/>
                            ^---^
refferenceEdit.jsp:35:29: Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an expression.
                     <c:out value="${metaData.tableName}"/>
                            ^---^
viewPA.jsp:117:26: Error in "C:\TFS\IT\CpsEnterprise\tempbuild\cpsent\jsp\include\closedPAs.jsi" at line 10: Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an expression.
        <%@ include file="/jsp/include/closedPAs.jsi" %>
                         ^--------------------------^
viewPA.jsp:117:26: Error in "C:\TFS\IT\CpsEnterprise\tempbuild\cpsent\jsp\include\closedPAs.jsi" at line 13: Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an expression.
        <%@ include file="/jsp/include/closedPAs.jsi" %>
                         ^--------------------------^
viewPA.jsp:117:26: Error in "C:\TFS\IT\CpsEnterprise\tempbuild\cpsent\jsp\include\closedPAs.jsi" at line 14: Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an expression.
        <%@ include file="/jsp/include/closedPAs.jsi" %>
                         ^--------------------------^
viewPA.jsp:117:26: Error in "C:\TFS\IT\CpsEnterprise\tempbuild\cpsent\jsp\include\closedPAs.jsi" at line 16: Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an expression.
        <%@ include file="/jsp/include/closedPAs.jsi" %>
                         ^--------------------------^
viewPA.jsp:117:26: Error in "C:\TFS\IT\CpsEnterprise\tempbuild\cpsent\jsp\include\closedPAs.jsi" at line 17: Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an expression.
        <%@ include file="/jsp/include/closedPAs.jsi" %>
                         ^--------------------------^
viewPA.jsp:117:26: Error in "C:\TFS\IT\CpsEnterprise\tempbuild\cpsent\jsp\include\closedPAs.jsi" at line 17: Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an expression.
        <%@ include file="/jsp/include/closedPAs.jsi" %>
                         ^--------------------------^
viewPA.jsp:117:26: Error in "C:\TFS\IT\CpsEnterprise\tempbuild\cpsent\jsp\include\closedPAs.jsi" at line 17: Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an expression.
        <%@ include file="/jsp/include/closedPAs.jsi" %>
                         ^--------------------------^
```